# Read two files and concat to same string but it fails

Tags: javascript, node.js

First of all, Sorry for my little english.
I made a node program for testing html/css snippets.
I hope to use in this way: `$node testing.js foo.html foo.css`, But it does not work. In fact, it pushed all sources between `<style>`tags.
I think that it is matter of file reading process, but I cannot figure it out.

```
var http = require("http"),
    fs = require("fs");
    filePath = process.argv;

if (filePath.length == 2) {
    console.log("need exactly 2 args for testing");
    return;
}

var htmlFile = filePath[2],
    cssFile = filePath[3];

var testHtml = "<!DOCTYPE html><html lang=\"en\"><head><meta charset=\"UTF-8\"><title>testing</title></head><body>"

fs.readFile(htmlFile, 'utf8', function(err, html) {
    if (err) {
        console.log("html module not found");
        throw err;
    }
    else {
        testHtml += html;
    }
});

testHtml += "</body><style>"

fs.readFile(cssFile, 'utf8', function(err, css) {
    if (err) {
        console.log("css module not found");
        throw err;
    }
    else {
        testHtml += css + "</style>";
    }
});

function onRequest(request, response) {
    console.log("Request Recieved");
    response.writeHead(200, {"Content-type": "text/html"});
    response.write(testHtml);
    response.end();
}

http.createServer(onRequest).listen(8001);
```

Comment: is `fs.readFile` asynchronous by chance? if so, you need to understand how to work with asynchronous code (though, in this case `fs.readFileSync` may be easier)

Comment: Thank you. I am new to node.js, I did not understand much about asynchronous processes. I will search for it.

Comment: `fs` is asynchronous isn't it?

Comment: I fixed it in this way: `testHtml += html +"</body><style>"` at line 30, and then it works. but I don't know yet why this code does not works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `fs.readFile` is asynchronous, you must perform the second file read within the callback function of the first.

```
fs.readFile(htmlFile, 'utf8', function(err, html) {
    if (err) {
        console.log("html module not found");
        throw err;
    }

    testHtml += html + "</body><style>";

    fs.readFile(cssFile, 'utf8', function(err, css) {
        if (err) {
            console.log("css module not found");
            throw err;
        }

        testHtml += css + "</style></html>";
    });
});
```

Otherwise you can use `readFileSync`.